# Safari App Extension content script not loaded on Safari error page?

Tags: safari, safari-app-extension, safari-content-script

When running a Safari App Extension, if Safari shows "Failed to open page", your content script isn't loaded. In this sort of scenario, it might be nice to redirect the user to a new url or suggestions page such as "did you mean...".

Is it possible to get a Safari App Extension's content script to load when a Safari error page is showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not appear to be possible.

Based on Apple's Safari App Extensions "[About Permissions for Scripts and Style Sheets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/safari_app_extension_info_property_list_keys/about_permissions_for_scripts_and_style_sheets)" documentation, I'm deducing that script injection only works on web content from `http://` or `https://` schemes, while error pages are loaded from local files.

> A URL pattern takes the form `Scheme://Domain/Path`.
>   (...) 
>   Scheme can be `http` or `https`. (...) 
>   The asterisk character can be used anywhere in the domain or path, but not in the scheme.

For reference, here's the path of a Safari 13 error page template.

```
file:///Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/StandardErrorPage.html
```